# after uninstall a package i get the error: missing gradle project configuration folder:.setting java(0)

Tags: react-native, method-missing

[click to see the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK0Nf.png)

I receive the error when I uninstalled react-native-youtube and react-native-video thos two packages.
"*npm uninstall react-native-youtube --no--save*", "*npm uninstall react-native-video --no--save*" I Uninstalled those package using this cmd. Now how can I solve this problem?